# How to keep selecting rows of RecyclerView during onClicks after pressing longClick?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView where I am selecting my rows only when I do onLongPress but what I want is that the first onLongClick will initiate the highlighting and then onClick on the row will select and de-select the particular rows and NOT onLongClick. After de-selecting the last selected row then onLongClick should initiate the highlighting again. I tried doing it with boolean variables. But it does not work. I am so confused. Any ideas?

This is what I have been upto.

```
if(onLongPressReceived) {
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(!onClickAnotherPressReceived) {
                        onClickPressReceived = true;
                        mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setmIsChecked(true);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        onClickAnotherPressReceived = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked());
            holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmIsChecked()){
                holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_selected));
            }else {
                //holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_long_pressed));
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if(onClickPressReceived && !onLongAnotherPressReceived)
            {
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked());
                holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getmIsChecked()){
                    holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_selected));
                }else {
                    //holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_long_pressed));
                    holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            //Checking whether a particular view is clicked or not
            if(onClickAnotherPressReceived && !onLongAnotherPressReceived)
            {
                holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_long_pressed));
                holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_unselected));
                holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked()) {
                    holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
            //Checking whether a particular view is clicked or not
        else{
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_long_pressed));
            holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.list_unselected));
            holder.mDeleteRow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (mItems.get(position).getmIsChecked()) {
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.checkboxHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }


        //Calls the interface method in Activity to respond to CheckBox changes
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                updateMainClass.updateListBackground(holder.getAdapterPosition(), b);
            }
        });
        /**
         * <p>Responds to long press made on any row</p>
         * <p>Checks the item on which long press is made
         * sets the onLongPressReceived status to true and notify the adapter to refresh the list.</p>
         */
        holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if(onLongAnotherPressReceived) {
                    onLongPressReceived = true;
                    mItems.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setmIsChecked(true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    onLongAnotherPressReceived = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        //Calls the interface in Activity to remove the item from the List.
        holder.mDeleteRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updateMainClass.updateItemList(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

In your `onBindViewHolder` call `bindView` method of `ViewHolder` class:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).bindView(getItem(position));
    }
```

Then in your viewHolder class do keep instance of your entity:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        YOUR_OBJECT entity;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //initialize view here
        }

        public void bindView(ChannelEntity entity) {

            this.entity = entity; // use this entity for longClickListener
            //setOnClickListener || OnLongClickListener Here
        }
    }
```